# Characterize "Algebraic operation" purely in terms of abstract algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Wikipedia defines "algebraic operation" as:

> an algebraic operation is any one of the traditional operations of arithmetic, which are addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, raising to an integer power, and taking roots (fractional power)

**Is there a way to characterize this set of operations based on very general and purely abstract algebraic concepts?** e.g. without making reference specifically to arithmetic?

**My question is prompted by** a later sentence in the same wikipedia article:

> They may also be performed, in a similar way, on variables, algebraic expressions, and, more generally on elements of algebraic structures, such as groups and fields

**EDIT**: Let me clarify my motivation, which I should have done immediately: Suppose we have a field $\mathbb F$. Then field addition $+_\mathbb F$ and field multiplication $\cdot_\mathbb F$ are defined, and by the axioms, also field subtraction $-_\mathbb F$ and field division $/_\mathbb F$. But, we automatically also have can define "*derived operators*" $\cdot_\mathbb Z:\mathbb F\times \mathbb Z\to \mathbb F$ (i.e. "$\mathbb Z$-multiplication") and $\text{pow}_\mathbb Z:\mathbb F\times \mathbb Z\to \mathbb F$ (i.e. "$\mathbb Z$-power"), because we can define $$nx=n\cdot_\mathbb Zx=\underbrace{x+_\mathbb Fx+_\mathbb F...+_\mathbb F \;x}_{\text{n times}}$$

$$x^n=x \;\text{pow}_\mathbb Z \;n=\underbrace{x\cdot_\mathbb Fx\cdot_\mathbb F\;...\cdot_\mathbb F\; x}_{\text{n times}}$$

These two new operators don't make use of any new structure above and beyond the field signature and field axioms. So (not including the taking roots), we can characterize the set of operations $\{+,-,\cdot,/,\text{pow}_\mathbb Z \}$ as "those operations that can be achieved by finite applications of the basic operations of the algebraic structure".

**My question is essentially**: Can we give a similar characterisation of the set that also includes fractional powers? e.g. We can ask something like: what is a minimal set of operations $\mathcal A$ that are "algebraically defined" like this (in the sense that they can be defined purely from the field operators, without making additional assumptions), and also allows you to build any function that is "algebraically defined"?

- It is not obvious to me that "raising to a fractional power" is an operation that we can define for any field, without making additional assumptions.
- It is also not obvious to me that there aren't any *other* operations that we can define (that aren't simply an application of $\cdot_\mathbb Z$ and $\text{pow}_\mathbb Z$).

Comment: I'm not sure what you want here...

Comment: Could you go into a bit more detail about your motivation?  It seems to me that all of the structures listed in the last excerpt (groups, fields, algebraic expressions) do come with arithmetic operations.

Comment: Answering your question is the purpose of abstract algebra. And $\Bbb{Z}$ is present everywhere in abelian groups and monoids thus in algebra. Or maybe you mean defining algebra at the logic theory level ?

Comment: @DonThousand, edited. Does this clarify?

Comment: @ErickWong, edited. Does this clarify?

Comment: Yes, this a lot more clear. You want a field where every element has $n$th roots for every $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: @DonThousand, so would you agree that "algebraic operation" is a maybe misleading term, because it might suggest that it refers to "operations that can be defined purely algebraically", but it actually refers to something much more specific? (namely something specific to a certain type of Field).

Comment: @user56834 I don't think I can decisively say that. Different mathematicians often use terms in slightly different ways, sadly.

Comment: You *might* be looking for the notion of [algebraic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function) which happily extends to multiple variables. This idea takes places solely in a field so I'm not sure it's exactly what you're looking for (since your definitions sort of use more than a field's internal structure when they reference $\mathbb Z$).

Comment: @MiloBrandt, is it correct to say that the set of algebraic functions is some kind of "maximal set" of functions that can be "algebraically defined" (for a Field)?

Comment: @user56834 Er, if you define all those terms conveniently - it really just is "an algebraic function is the set of pairs $(x,y)$ determined as the roots of some polynomial" which is all you can do purely within the language of a field.

Comment: @MiloBrandt, sorry, I meant: "is that really all you can do purely within the language of a field"? as in, is there some kind of proof that you can't do anything more? (sorry in advance if this question doesn't make sense)

Comment: @user56834 If your criteria is "this function is defined by an equation using only the symbols $(0,1,+,-,*,^{-1})$, elements of the field, and the input and output of the function as variables" then it's relatively easy to see that you can't do better than algebraic functions - every expression will, after all, be an equality of rational functions and then you can clear denominators. However, if you wanted to allow quantifiers... well, then things can get really weird really fast (e.g. you start having Diophantine sets, which turned out, by a theorem of Matiyasevich, to be quite general)